# SQL Query - Run query multiple times but with a different variable date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lengthy query written in SQL that uses CTEs and multiple variables to produce a report of about 1500 customer records with many columns based on a particular date, @ToDate. Some of the tables are ordered CTEs so I only get the latest value based on the @ToDate.

I've omitted specifics but the structure is as follows:

```
Declare @ToDate date .....
Declare @Category varchar ....;

with cte1 as (select * from table1 where table1.start_date <= @ToDate and (table1.end_date > @ToDate or table1.end_date is null))
,cte2 as (select * from table2 where table2.start_date <= @ToDate and (table2.end_date > @ToDate or table2.end_date is null))

select * from cte1 
left join cte2 on cte2.id = cte1.id
where .....
```

which gives me the following results

```
|RunDate   |CustomerID|DOB       |Category|Col5  |Col6  |
|----------|----------|----------|--------|------|------|
|2021-08-30|11111     |2000-01-01|Cat1    |      |      |
|2021-08-30|22222     |2000-02-02|Cat2    |      |      |
```

I'd like to run the same script multiple times but with a different date. So run with @ToDate = '2021-08-30' which gives me one set of results and then every past Monday n number of times which would give me results like this...

```
|RunDate   |CustomerID|DOB       |Category|Col5  |Col6
|----------|----------|----------|--------|------|------|
|2021-08-30|11111     |2000-01-01|Cat1    |      |      |
|2021-08-30|22222     |2000-02-02|Cat2    |      |      |
|2021-08-23|11111     |2000-01-01|Cat1    |      |      |
|2021-08-23|22222     |2000-02-02|Cat2    |      |      |
|2021-08-23|33333     |2000-03-03|Cat9    |      |      |
```

I do have a calendar table available so I can easily identify the past n Mondays (or other day I like).

The only variable to change is the @ToDate as this is the Run Date, or As At Date if you will. Essentially I want to run it multiple times for the past few Mondays so I can get what the results were like at 30-08, 23-08, 16-08 etc...

I've never used loops and research suggests I should maybe avoid them or use them as a last resort. I'm not sure on the best approach and if I do use loops, how I wrap it around my query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the table1.date What do these tables look like, bit confused about the <= @ToDate and if you pass '2021-08-30' then '2021-08-23' you are getting just 7 days less data. Do you just want a range of date for that week e.g from '2021-08-30' - 7 days only?

Comment: Surely running for the most recent `@ToDate` will include all the rows for all other `@ToDate` values when run at a point in time. It's not clear without seeing a complete set of sample data and expected results.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Apologies, I wasn't very clear now that I have re-read it. In trying to simplify the request I have omitted one key piece of information related to the ToDate. I've updated the question. Essentially, my query gives me performance data as of the ToDate, but I want to "loop" through a number of times for previous dates, so I get one set of results.

Answer (score 0):

The question really needs a bit more elaboration but I have give a guess at what you are trying to do with this example.

I have create a Customers and Orders table and then display the results for the date range

[image]

I don't think you need to loop with cursors and such as you can get the loop effect by just using the #DateRanges and join on that. it being a CTE or not.

Please let me know if this is not what you meant and I will remove the answer

```
-- Setup a temp table to hold the dates I want to look for
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O WHERE O.xtype in ('U') AND O.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#DateRanges'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Removing temp table #DateRanges'
    DROP TABLE #DateRanges;
END

CREATE TABLE #DateRanges (
    [Date] DATE
)
-- Add some dates
INSERT INTO #DateRanges ([Date])
VALUES ('2021-08-30'), 
('2021-08-23'), 
('2021-08-16')

-- Setup some customers
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O WHERE O.xtype in ('U') AND O.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#Customers'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Removing temp table #Customers'
    DROP TABLE #Customers;
END

CREATE TABLE #Customers (
    CustomerId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
    DOB DATE NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_CustomerId PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId)
)

INSERT INTO #Customers ([Name], DOB) 
VALUES('Bob', '1989-01-01'),
('Robert', '1994-01-01'),
('Andrew', '1992-01-01');


-- Setup some orders
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects O WHERE O.xtype in ('U') AND O.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#Order'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Removing temp table #Order'
    DROP TABLE #Order;
END

CREATE TABLE #Order (
    OrderId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    CustomerId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Category NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_OrderId PRIMARY KEY (OrderId)
)

INSERT INTO #Order(CustomerId, CreatedDate, Category)
VALUES
(1, '2021-08-30', 'Cat1'),
(1, '2021-08-23', 'Cat2'),

(2, '2021-08-30', 'Cat1'),
(2, '2021-08-23', 'Cat2'),
(2, '2021-08-16', 'Cat3'),

(3, '2021-08-30', 'Cat1'),
(3, '2021-08-16', 'Cat2')

-- Using the #DateRanged temp table we can the use this to ge the data we need so no need for a loop

 SELECT * 
    FROM #DateRanges AS DR
    LEFT JOIN #Order AS O ON O.
CreatedDate <= DR.[Date] AND O.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(D, -6, DR.[Date])
```